# Amending a condition as the stack unwinds in Common Lisp

Tags: exception, common-lisp

I'm working on some lisp code that munges a CVS repository in order to get it into shape for a git conversion. As such, when something goes wrong it might not be a bug in my code but might instead be an inaccuracy in the input data which needs fixing.

Deep down in the bowels of my code, I'll have (say) some function that merges two date ranges by taking an intersection. If that intersection turns out to be empty, I'll raise an error. This is all good, but my "merge dates" function is missing lots of the information that the user (me!) needs in order to figure out what went wrong. For example, which CVS master file ("foo,v") was I working on? What branch was I thinking about? Etc. etc.

My partial solution to this problem is to handle and re-raise the error. For example, this sort of code:

```
             (handler-case
                 (do-something)
               (unclear-graft-point (c)
                 (setf (slot-value c 'master) master)
                 (setf (slot-value c 'branch) branch)
                 (error c)))
```

which sets some extra slots with useful info before re-raising the error.

The report function for the condition then checks whether those slots have been set and, if so, will use them to give a more helpful error message.

Unfortunately, the backtrace that I get stops at the top-level re-raise. That makes sense: it's the code I wrote. But it's not really what I want...

Is there a way in Common Lisp to "annotate" a condition as it hurtles past, without re-raising it and, hence, partially unwinding the stack without reporting that in the back trace?

I gave a reasonable amount of background info about what I'm doing in the hope that, if this isn't possible, someone will say "Ah, what you should do in this situation is...": am I just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: When you signal an error, the stack is _not_ unwound in Common Lisp.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the hyperspec only indicates that condition slots are readable. No guarantees are made regarding any ability to modify slot values for a condition object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a Common Lisp technology applicapble to your case - it is called [HANDLER-BIND](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_handler-bind.html). You can find a detailed explanation and use cases for it alongside other condition-handling machinery in Peter Seibel's Practical Common Lisp [Chapter  19. Conditions and Restarts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html).